# UnsatisfiedLinkError with Here Maps Android

Tags: here-api

I have two devices with the same Android os (7.0). One is a Nexus 6 and the other is a Samsung Galaxy Note 5. The Nexus will load the map fine, but the Samsung crashes at:

```
MapEngine.getInstance().init(getActivity(), new OnEngineInitListener() {...}
```

with the following error:

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.uzurv.android.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.uzurv.android.myapp-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.uzurv.android.myapp-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libanalytics_jni.so"**

Furthermore, the map seems to work on every other device and OS we have, all the way back to 4.4.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Just in case, if some one is experiencing the same issue, I got it solved by building the apk by gradlew assembleDebug or any other variant.
It seems that android studio while building the apk it customises the build for the current emulator, or connected device or so, weird, but this is how it worked for me! building from the terminal not Android Studio!

Comment: We ended up dropping here maps so this problem fixed itself. If you want to put your comment into an answer I'll accept it, though.